# запуск jar в ubuntu двойным кликом

Tags: java

Как сделать так, чтобы в Ubuntu можно было запускать jar двойным кликом?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click

Comment: Это я пробовал, но проблема в том, что в открывшемся списке нет ничего, что касается Java

Comment: Значит надо установить jre или jdk

Comment: Установлено. Я же из консоли запускал - все работает

Answer (score 1):

Создайте файл `/usr/share/applications/java.desktop` с нижеприведенным содержимым, и тогда соответствующий лаунчер должен появиться в диалоге "Открыть с помощью":

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Java
Comment=Java
GenericName=Java
Keywords=java
Exec=java -jar %f
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
MimeType=application/x-java-archive
StartupNotify=true
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, я так и сделал. Только всеравно не то, что надо - надо, чтобы открывалась консоль и вывод программы должен оставаться в консоли, пока я ее не закрою. А так получилось, что программа где-то там на фоне отработала и не известно, что она сделала. Так что забил и просто открываю консоль и оттуда запускаю программу.